# Xamarin C# .jar wrapping

Tags: c#, jar, binding, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to crate a binding for SQLCypher for android in Xamarin and I get 4 errors I can't seem to overcome.

The 4 errors are:

> Error CS0534: 'BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor' does not implement inherited
>   abstract member 'AbstractCursor.GetType(int)' (CS0534) (SQLCyper)

```
public sealed partial class BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor : global::Info.Guardianproject.Database.AbstractWindowedCursor {
```

---

> Error CS0534: 'MatrixCursor' does not implement inherited abstract
>   member 'AbstractCursor.GetType(int)' (CS0534) (SQLCyper)

```
public partial class MatrixCursor : global::Info.Guardianproject.Database.AbstractCursor {
```

---

> Error CS0738: 'AbstractCursor' does not implement interface member
>   'ICrossProcessCursor.Window'. 'AbstractCursor.Window' cannot implement
>   'ICrossProcessCursor.Window' because it does not have the matching
>   return type of 'CursorWindow'. (CS0738) (SQLCyper)

```
public abstract partial class AbstractCursor : global::Java.Lang.Object, global::Android.Database.ICrossProcessCursor {
```

---

> Error CS0534: 'SQLiteCursor' does not implement inherited abstract
>   member 'AbstractCursor.GetType(int)' (CS0534) (SQLCyper)

```
public partial class SQLiteCursor : global::Info.Guardianproject.Database.AbstractWindowedCursor
```

---

As you see, 3 are the similar.

My Xamarin is up to date, the target platform is, Android 4.1 jellybean.

The source of the jar file is: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadsqlcipherjar.htm

Another jar file I'm trying with is: http://www.trojanpc.co.za/sqlcipher.jar

This one I took from an android project that had this jar in it, this one has different errors in it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to create the Bindings on your own. They are available as Xamarin Component.

Android: https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/sqlcipher-for-xamarin-android

iOS: https://components.xamarin.com/view/sqlcipher-for-xamarin-ios

General Info: https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-for-xamarin/

**Or**

I don't know how old the linked jar is. So I decided, to build the binding based on the latest community edition.

What have I done:

1. Add android-database-sqlcipher-3.3.1-2.aar [1] to the jar folder
2. Set the build action of it to `LibraryProjectZip`
3. got rid of the build errors by extending the meta data

   ```
   <metadata>
       <attr path="/api/package[@name='net.sqlcipher']/class[@name='AbstractCursor']/method[@name='getWindow' and count(parameter)=0]" name="managedReturn">Android.Database.CursorWindow</attr>
       <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='net.sqlcipher']/interface[@name='Cursor']/method[@name='getType' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='int']]"></remove-node>
   </metadata>
   ```

   This sets the return of the Window property to `Android.Database.CursorWindow` because the interface expects it.
   And removes a redundant `getType` method.

   4. Compiled it without errors.
   5. pushed it to a github repository: https://github.com/smstuebe/xamarin-sqlcipher

I did not test it. Feel free to send a pull request, if you find an error.

[1] https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/net.zetetic%3Aandroid-database-sqlcipher/3.3.1-2/view

Comment: Thanks but I don't have $500 for those bindings, hence trying to create my own ones.. I wish I did have the $500 for it thou ....

Comment: Ok, I'll have a look at it, when I'm at home. I guess its just some meta data xml magic and some partial class extensions.

Comment: Thanks you so much, hopefully it does not take too much of your time, the problem lies in them being abstract members , I think ..

Comment: I've had a closer look at it and used the latest version. Have a look at my updated answer.